# Calculate a value and update this in a GUI python, without block my gui

Tags: python, pyqt, pthreads

I have a simple application, one label and 2 buttons ( start increment, stop increment), write in pyqt5.

When I pres start button want to see in ui, value update in real time and have acces at stop button.

Now when I press start button, not see an update in UI and when try to press on stop receive not responding.

One solution probably is Threads, but I don't understand how work thread's in Python

```
import sys
import time
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QPushButton, QLineEdit
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    running = True
    value = 1

def __init__(self):
    QMainWindow.__init__(self)
    self.setMinimumSize(QSize(600, 500))
    self.setMaximumSize(QSize(600, 500))
    self.setWindowTitle("Demo app")
    QApplication.setStyle("fusion")
    self.move(1000, 200)

    self.button_start = QPushButton('Start', self)
    self.button_start.setFixedHeight(40)
    self.button_start.setFixedWidth(170)
    self.button_start.move(10, 215)
    self.button_start.clicked.connect(self.start_function)
    self.update()

    self.button_stop = QPushButton('Stop', self)
    self.button_stop.setFixedHeight(40)
    self.button_stop.setFixedWidth(170)
    self.button_stop.move(200, 215)
    self.button_stop.setDisabled(True)
    self.button_stop.clicked.connect(self.stop_function)
    self.update()

    self.label = QLineEdit(self)
    self.label.move(10, 170)
    self.label.resize(170, 40)
    self.label.setEnabled(False)
    self.label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
    self.label.setStyleSheet("color: red;")
    self.update()

def start_function(self):
    self.button_start.setDisabled(True)
    self.button_stop.setDisabled(False)
    while self.running is True:
        self.value += 1
        self.label.setText(str(self.value))
        print("Value: ", self.value)
        time.sleep(1)

def stop_function(self):
    self.running = False


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWin = MainWindow()
    mainWin.show()
    mainWin.update()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @S.Nick now is more good ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm a little late and you figured out yourself how to solve this problem, but for those with the same issue:

You can't set a loop in the GUI thread for this purpose, It will block the GUI thread from doing anything. Instead, You can use QTimer to schedule something to run at a later point in time. You can use it to implement something like a stopwatch.

Here is a functional minimal example:

```
import sys
import time
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QPushButton, QLineEdit
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    value = 0

    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(600, 500))
        self.setMaximumSize(QSize(600, 500))
        self.setWindowTitle("Demo app")
        QApplication.setStyle("fusion")
        self.move(1000, 200)

        self.button_start = QPushButton('Start', self)
        self.button_start.setFixedHeight(40)
        self.button_start.setFixedWidth(170)
        self.button_start.move(10, 215)
        self.button_start.clicked.connect(self.start_function)
        self.update()

        self.button_stop = QPushButton('Stop', self)
        self.button_stop.setFixedHeight(40)
        self.button_stop.setFixedWidth(170)
        self.button_stop.move(200, 215)
        self.button_stop.setDisabled(True)
        self.button_stop.clicked.connect(self.stop_function)
        self.update()

        self.label = QLineEdit(self)
        self.label.move(10, 170)
        self.label.resize(170, 40)
        self.label.setEnabled(False)
        self.label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("color: red;")
        self.label.setText(str(self.value))
        self.update()

        self.workTimer = QTimer()
        self.workTimer.setInterval(1000)
        self.workTimer.timeout.connect(self.increase_value)

    def start_function(self):
        self.workTimer.start()

        self.button_start.setDisabled(True)
        self.button_stop.setDisabled(False)

    def stop_function(self):
        self.workTimer.stop()

        self.button_start.setDisabled(False)
        self.button_stop.setDisabled(True)

    def increase_value(self):
        self.value += 1
        self.label.setText(str(self.value))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWin = MainWindow()
    mainWin.show()
    mainWin.update()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```